# Databinding with Livedata not showing values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-databinding

**Update:**
I found out that there is a problem with the async task, while setting the `LiveData`

I'm using MVVM in my App and I try to bind Livedata to a TextView with Jetpack Databinding.

I get the correct values in the `Log.d()` of my Viewmodel, however the data is not shown on Screen.

Could someone guess what am I missing?

**My XML File**

(fragment_lobbyleader.xml)

```
   <data >
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.beerrallye.lobby.newLobbyData.LobbyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lobbyleader_lobbyCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.lobbyID}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lobbyleader_player_textview"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**My Viewmodel**

```
class LobbyViewModel(private val lobbyRepository: LobbyRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _lobbyID = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val lobbyID : LiveData<String?> = _lobbyID

    fun createLobby(lobby: Lobby) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = lobbyRepository.createLobby(lobby)
            Log.d("Lobby", "Viewmodel Data: ${result}")

            if (result is Result.Success) {
               
                _lobbyID.value = result.data.lobbyID

                Log.d("Lobby", "Viewmodel Data: ${_lobbyID.value}")
          
        }

    }
}
```

**My Fragment**

```
class LobbyLeaderFragment : Fragment() {
    private val  lobbyViewmodel: LobbyViewModel by viewModels {
        LobbyViewModelFactory((activity?.application as AppApplication).lobbyRepository)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding: FragmentLobbyleaderBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_lobbyleader,
            container,
            false
        )

        binding.viewmodel = lobbyViewmodel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        lobbyViewmodel.lobbyID.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.d("Lobby", "LobbyCode: $it")
        })

        return binding.root
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding Adapter live data value is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755154/binding-adapter-live-data-value-is-always-null)

Answer (score 0):

Can try switching the order of

```
    binding.viewmodel = lobbyViewmodel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```

And turn it into

```
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    binding.viewmodel = lobbyViewmodel
```

It's probable that when it wants to observe livedata, the lifecycleOwner is null and thus it cannot observe it

Also check this [Binding Adapter live data value is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755154/binding-adapter-live-data-value-is-always-null/66755692#66755692)

Comment: that didn't solve the problem. I don't know how to check if it's null, because it's just show nothing in the view. Furthermore I tried to debug the LiveData value with an observable, however it's not showing the `Log.d` I've added. (I've edited my post)